# Web Server for SVN+PHP+Django+Rails

Tags: apache-http-server, php, ruby-on-rails, nginx, django

*Foreword:* I am not asking for the differences between Nginx and Apache, nor do I want to start a "*which one is better* discussion.

I would like to ask for help with choosing the most adequate solution for this particular situation. I need to setup one or more l SVN repositories accessible via HTTP, plus some PHP, Django and Ruby websites. However, and since I only have 512Mb of RAM at my disposal, I fear that Apache will be a too heavy choice... On the other hand, I have heard that Nginx does not fully support SVN (WebDAV) and Django without reverse proxying to Apache. Is this still true? Should I go for Apache/Nginx alone? Or should I set up both and have Nginx handling static content and proxying to Apacge for dynamic content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx is smaller, simpler and more pleasant to configure, and I recommend pursuing it as your sole web server.

[According to the Nginx WebDAV page](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpDavModule), full WebDAV support is now available by combining the 'http_dav_module' with complementary module available that the page links to on GitHub.

Documentation is available elsewhere for running [Django on Nginx](http://www.derekschaefer.net/2011/06/07/nginx-django-yay/) and [PHP on Nginx](http://interfacelab.com/nginx-php-fpm-apc-awesome/). Tutorials for running Rails on Nginx easily found as well.

Whether 512 MB of RAM will still be sufficient will depend on a number of factors. I recommend having some swap space available in case things are tight.